Как использовать Telegram API для создания клиентов в Java?
Какие есть библиотеки для работы с телеграм аккаунтами в Java?
В Python, к примеру, есть библиотека telethon для рабоыт с телеграм аккаунтами.
Получаю hash_api и hash_id и создаю сессию и все могу работать.
В C# есть библиотека WTelegramClient.
А вот в Java, какой аналог этому?

Телеграм предоставляет API для создания клиентов. На Java можно создавать клиентов с помощью этого ресурса.


Telegram Client API на Java
обычно используется для создания собственных клиентов Telegram на Java. Он предоставляет полный доступ к всем функциям Telegram, включая отправку и получение сообщений, управление группами и каналами, а также многие другие функции. Некоторые из основных функций Telegram Client API на Java включают:

Отправка и получение текстовых сообщений, фотографий, видео, аудио, документов и других типов медиафайлов.
Управление группами и каналами, включая создание, редактирование, добавление и удаление участников.
Получение обновлений о новых сообщениях, редактированных сообщениях, входящих звонках и других событиях.
Управление контактами, включая добавление, удаление и редактирование контактов.
Управление звонками, включая инициацию, принятие и завершение звонков.



Для более детального изучения Telegram APIs нужно обращаться к источнику.

простите не понял что вы имели ввиду под "Телеграм предоставляет API для создания клиентов" ? И на счет библиотеки она официальная (возможно глупый вопрос) ?

и не знаете есть ли примеры использование этой библиотеки, что-то я не нашел примеров.

Если перейти в родительскую папку, то там полно примеров.

смотрите в папке src main вот там вот я нашел main/java/org.telegram/api/account и там есть файлы но я не нашел среди них в коде строки где увидел бы hasp_api и hash_id они нужны для авторизации в тг аккаунте. Или в этой библиотеке по другому? (Простите что странные вопросы задаю)

Там есть туториал по API и пример где-то в репозитории, эти значения нужно получить сразу при регистрации приложения, чтобы можно было пользоваться библиотекой.
